# Python code for Binary Search Algorithm does not compile

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to implement a Binary Search algorithm in Python.
I wrote this code on my phone but it didn't compile.
And I don't know why it doesn't compile.
(I haven't tried it on a computer.)

```
def BinarySearch(sList, search):
    res=0
    sortedList=sorted(sList)
    x=int(len(sortedList)/2)
    mid=sortedList[x]
    def DivideSearch(sortedList ,search ):
        first=sortedList[:mid ]
        second=sortedList[mid:]
        if first[len(first)-1]<search:
            DivideSearch (first, search)
        elif second[len(second)-1]>search:
            DivideSearch (second, search)
        elif len(first)==1:
            res=first.pop()
        elif len(second)==1:
            res=second.pop()
    if res==search:
        return res


numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
guess=3

print(BinarySearch(numbers,guess ))
```

What keeps this code from compiling?
What are my mistakes and how can I fix them?

Comment: you should include the error it gives you in your question!!!,and the indentation is not good,,,,you should learn about python indentation http://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan i haven't error and i haven't result

Comment: the indentation is very bad, return res is under if.res==search,in the case res is not equal to search, it wont return anything...therefore you wont see anything..and again..its hard to tell with your indentation..first fix it..!

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan i didn't see indenting after asking question. I'm sorry. I'll edit this.

Comment: `x=int(len(sortedList)/2)` is calculated once, move it inside `DivideSearch`.

Comment: `mid` is `x` not `mid=sortedList[x]`

Comment: you have to call `DivideSearch` inside `BinarySearch`

Comment: first problem...DivideSearch is never called..that why it return None,you should call it as return statement of BinarySearch(You cant call a function before it gets defined)

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: python doesn't do compilation. The code itself runs without an error. So its not syntax/undefined variable error but an error in the logic of the function. If you want to see how to do a binary search look at the [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/bisect.py) of the bisect module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your code is running fine on my machine. Second, your logic is flawed. `res` never gets assigned in the `BinarySearch()` function because it is in a different scope than in the parent function. Also, your base case check should not be done on `first` or `second` it should be done on `sortedList` at the beginning of the function. Also, you can do your checking if the value was found in the `DivideSearch()` function.  I'm uploading corrected code, take a look at this

```
import random
def DivideSearch(sortedList, search, mid):
    first = sortedList[:mid]
    second = sortedList[mid:]
    #check for our base case
    if len(sortedList) ==1:
        return sortedList[0] if sortedList[0] == search else None
    #we can immediately remove half the cases if they're less than or greater than our search value
    #if the greatest value element in the lower half is < search value, only search the higher value list
    if first[-1] < search:
        #recurse
        return DivideSearch(second, search, len(second)/2)

    #otherwise we want to check the lower value list
    else:
        return DivideSearch(first, search, len(first)/2)

def BinarySearch(sList, search):

    sortedList=sorted(sList)
    #determine mid cleanup
    mid=len(sortedList)/2
    #return the result
    return DivideSearch(sortedList,search, mid)



numbers=[random.randint(1, 10) for x in range(1,10)]
guess=5
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def binarys(list, item):

   #you have to keep track of the head(lo) of the list and tail(hi)

   lo = 0

   #a list must be sorted for binary search to work because the lower values are on the left and higher on the right

   slist = sorted(list)
   hi = len(slist) - 1

  #Keep running the search as long as the start of the list is never less than or equal to the end of the list. At that point you either have 1 item left to check or the item isn't there at all. So return False

   while lo <= hi:
      mid = (lo + hi)//2

      #if the item you searched for is in the middle, return True
      if slist[mid] == item:
         return True

      #since it's not in the middle the first time you checked, but if the item you're looking for is less than the value of the mid item in the list then you can ignore the entire right part of the list by making the item to the left of the midpoint the new tail(hi). midpoint minus 1 because you already established the midpoint of the original list didn't have the item you searched for.
      elif item < slist[mid]:
         hi = mid - 1

      # if the item you're looking for is greater than the value of the mid item in the list then you can ignore the entire left part of the list by making the item to the right of the midpoint the new head(lo). midpoint plus 1 because you already established the midpoint of the original list didn't have the item you searched for.
      else:
         if item > slist[mid]:
            lo = mid+ 1
   return False

print(binarys([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 1))
```

Comment: That might be a correct version of the code, but you give no context or explanation.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the OP wanted to know *why* their code does not compile. Just giving them the code of your own implementation of a binary search doe not help them in any way.

Comment: Added comments to explain

Comment: That still doesn't tell the OP why *their code* doesn't compile, which is the actual question.

Comment: yes but I'm showing probably the easiest way of doing the search. I'm not forcing him to use it.